# Using Bearer/Jwt authorization without Identity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm developing a Web API with Asp 5 and reading some documents about Web API realize I need Bearer authorization.

After searching I can't find any document or sample that use authorization without `Aspnet.Identity`. I have my own membership and I don't want to use `Identity`
Should I use `Identity` library? or is there a way to implement authorization in my membership.

**One little side question:**
if I'm forced to use Identity how can I change EntityFramework to something like dapper or ADO.NET for my `DBContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To issue your own JWT tokens, you can use [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/core):

### project.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.Mvc": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

### Startup.cs

```c#
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        {
            // Configure the context to use an in-memory store.
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase();

            // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
            // Note: use the generic overload if you need
            // to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
        {
            // Register the Entity Framework stores.
            options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<DbContext>();

            // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
            // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
            // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
            options.AddMvcBinders();

            // Enable the token endpoint.
            options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

            // Enable the password flow.
            options.AllowPasswordFlow();

            // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
            options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Register the validation middleware, that is used to decrypt
        // the access tokens and populate the HttpContext.User property.
        app.UseOAuthValidation();

        // Register the OpenIddict middleware.
        app.UseOpenIddict();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

### AuthorizationController.cs

```c#
public class AuthorizationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
    public IActionResult Exchange(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            // Validate the user credentials.
            // Note: to mitigate brute force attacks, you SHOULD strongly consider
            // applying a key derivation function like PBKDF2 to slow down
            // the password validation process. You SHOULD also consider
            // using a time-constant comparer to prevent timing attacks.
            if (request.Username != "alice@wonderland.com" ||
                request.Password != "P@ssw0rd")
            {
                return Forbid(OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }

            // Create a new ClaimsIdentity holding the user identity.
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);

            // Add a "sub" claim containing the user identifier, and attach
            // the "access_token" destination to allow OpenIddict to store it
            // in the access token, so it can be retrieved from your controllers.
            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
                "71346D62-9BA5-4B6D-9ECA-755574D628D8",
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name, "Alice",
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

            // ... add other claims, if necessary.
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            // Ask OpenIddict to generate a new token and return an OAuth2 token response.
            return SignIn(principal, OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
    }
}
```

### Request

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7096
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=alice%40wonderland.com&password=P%40ssw0rd
```

### Response

```json
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "CfDJ8Ec0ZpniaHhGg0e0UUvOH9BWZSGrPoEwGd0_Lq2cse-T29YOq985IBiT5fEe5tTSgY1vxq2Z2ZJ7Ikwlpmh0Lrc4x9pqhqHBziUzsP_rkGZkn47TkNkOkzKCwZJZK5x-irH3HROwClFFTq0rgWdb8rZ2xriffNzsby4VwhxhN5soFD435KzmVYkdv-VuaLYo3QiSuexbRi2USVO9LK30vomAG6h2SAxZ7R-jYsXgf0f5gAmdYxg7w3yicv9v8DpUSBiGGRRfymTOnvGEsFJjGuuP8OlY5qzMs6wGaRWkOvCyV2CK_RZF_3TMs7LYCdMQ-dqWY5A03-03OmP8blKzlrKJMDZfrPQHuysbS931xxy8b3kjicfjNLmMHqzQzbUO4fecm4kY8PFnKozojDtqajfTp2bYhxS65bmVYROrswYeUWEKYR6LSdS1K__IDaLoMlLa-Wf6x1wjM2CchzgqbHRF0KEtdL5Ks88dAS44mp9BM6iUOEWyL7VkbazsBdlNciM5ZZB1_6qunufDW_tcaR8",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

For more information, you can read this blog post I wrote about OpenIddict: http://kevinchalet.com/2017/01/30/implementing-simple-token-authentication-in-aspnet-core-with-openiddict/

Comment: I have some question : **1**- I can't  call `/connect/token` from `50000` port and I must call it from default IIS Express port. is it right or i do something wrong? **2**- Is there a way to change `/connect/token` to any Url I want?

Comment: Of course, the `50000` was just a sample and you need to use the one assigned to your application. You can replace the default path in the middleware options (`options.TokenEndpointPath = "/my-path"`).

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. I'm starting writing my membership middleware. I will ask more questions later maybe :-)

Comment: You're welcome. If you have other questions, don't hesitate to use the `[aspnet-contrib]` tag.

Comment: I can't understand why this answer is the solution of your question. He use entity framework.

Comment: Why do you need EntityFramework if all validation is done manually?

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin I replied to your post here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/937#issuecomment-645966904.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a [JWT Bearer middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer), you just need to write something that issues bearer tokens. That's a little more complicated, depending on what you use as your identity store, and as you indicate it's something custom, it's hard to advise on any approach. Creating JWT tokens isn't that hard though;

```c#
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

// Creates new keys automatically, you'd want to store these somewhere
var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

var signingTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, "YOURWEBSITEURL")                    }),
                    TokenIssuerName = "YourWebSite",
                    Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, now.AddHours(1)),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                        new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(aes.Key),
                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256")
                };

var token = signingTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
var tokenAsString = signingTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

None of the authorization pieces depend on membership at all, they'll work with any authentication middleware. None of the documentation for authorization even refers to Identity at all.

There's an [authorization workshop](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop) available. You can see in the source for that that no-one does identity appear, it's creating user principals on the fly and then storing them in cookies.

Comment: What about my side question?

Comment: Identity is linked to ef.

Comment: That's unfortunate for me. Thanks

Comment: @blowdart: linked is too vague. Identity is absolutely not tied to EF: you can definitely write your own user store (of course, referencing EF is not necessary). Concerning your code sample, I'm still trying to figure out why you're using AesCSP which is not needed and won't work on cross-platform scenarios (since it's tied to CAPI)

Comment: It was a simple sample :p (And sure, but when you're at the point of writing your own user store, meh, you may as well do it all yourself IMO)

Comment: (And AesManaged no longer exists in core, and, err, Aes is virtual) In fact there doesn't seem to be any cross platform symmetric algorithm yet. Oh dear.

Comment: Meh, why using AES here? You don't need it at all. Just use RandomNumberGenerator.Create and fill an array whose length corresponds to the key length you need to generate your symmetric key.

Comment: Or go asymmetric. But still, simple sample still stands.

Comment: Simple doesn't mean bad, does it? :P I'll post an ASOS or OpenIddict sample, you'll see what simple means :P

Comment: @Raika yep. It would help if you added more information about your exact needs: how do your users authenticate with your website? Password, social provider? Do you want consent screens to allow your users to decide if they want to grant your apps access to their resources? Or would you prefer something like the resource owner password grant offered by OAuth2? (basically, a single username/password request returning an access token).

Comment: @Pinpoint . Password would be fine but if social provider is possible this is way better (or mixed password and social provider :D ) . and I don't need any access to their resources. just as you say **basically, a single username/password request returning an access token**