# Custom role based Authorization in Asp.Net Core Web API 5.0 & Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an already existing database containing Two tables like User Details, UserRole. Each user can have many custom roles. I have an Angular UI application, when UI calls any action method in any of the controller, then How will I check for the User role to check for Authorization? Note-: UI will send me the UserID on every request. I don't want to use Asp.Net Identity for user Authorization. How to proceed in this situation?
Do I need to query the Database in every action method which requires Authorization & fetch the role of the user?

Comment: How your angular ui realize the sign in action? I mean when users signed in, then you may save user id, user roles in the session or using redis to save these data in the memory.

Comment: On login, we are sending the user roles to UI by querying database & UI is storing those roles in shared service. But during other Api calls, UI will send me the UserID of the logged in user. I have to determine the roles assigned to the user based on User id.

Comment: How about adding a filter for this kind of calling, and in the filter you can query the database for obtaining the user role then save the roles in the session, and in the filter method, check the session before querying database.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JSON Web Tokens (JWT).  You don't need to use ASP.NET identity to use JWT.  When the user logs in, create a JWT on the server that contains who they are and what their roles are, then pass that back to your Angular client.

The client then needs to pass that JWT with each service request in a header that will look something like:

```js
{ "Authorization": "bearer <your token>" }
```

This way, your service code won't need to look up the user in the DB on every request.  It's also more secure, as properly signed JWTs can't be hacked, while if you're just passing an unencrypted UserId which someone could easily set a breakpoint in Chrome dev tools, and manually change to whatever they wanted.

Check out [Using Bearer/Jwt authorization without Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905754/using-bearer-jwt-authorization-without-identity/34906980) and https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually I know that we can add claims in jwt. But the problem is, I can't expose the user roles in jwt.

Comment: When you say you can't expose the user roles in JWT, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I meant to say, If you attach the user roles to your jwt as claims, then if you go to jwt.io & decode the payload, then you will be able to see those claims.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  But the claims can't be altered on the client without invalidating the signature, so as long as you validate the signature on the server, you know it's legit.